# Prove that exists two coincident "interesting" triangles.

Tags: geometry

Some vertices of a regular nonagon are coloured black, the rest of them are coloured green. A triangle is  "interesting" if all of its vertices are the same colour. Prove that exists two coincident "interesting" triangles.

I do not know how to prove this. Help me! Maybe  with pigeonhole principle?

Comment: What does "coincident" mean in this context?  The usual meaning does not seem to make sense...

Comment: maybe it means "congruent" (the poster talks about a **regular** nonagon...)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that any red/green vertex colouring of $K_9$ contains two monochromatic triangles which share exactly one vertex? At least five of the vertices are the same colour, and any monochromatic $K_5$ contains two such triangles.